# Display Base64 image data from an SQL Server database in Android ListView

Tags: android

I have saved an image from a mobile camera through an Android application to a SQL Server database along with some other columns with text data.

Now I want to display the data in Android List View, and I am able to display the text fields. But I am not able to display the saved image.

Comment: Well show what you already have. And why are things mentioned in the subject not in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to encode an image:

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving the image in the mobile storage and saving the path of the image in the database. This is a much faster and efficient of doing things.